# click event doesn't occur for the elements which have been added dynamically in jquery, although it works fine if loaded with the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events, dom

I made a research on this topic but couldn't find the solution to my question. Does the DOM needs to refresh, or is there any other logic behind this.

I have an anchor tag which on click invokes some random jquery function. If I load the anchor element while loading the page, the function executes absolutely fine, but if I load that anchor with some events of another elements causing it to load by some another function. then after clicking that anchor element, the required jquery funciton doesn't show up. Solutions Please.

Comment: For the 100000 time: delegation :)

Comment: Please use the SEARCH function or google...

Comment: @A.Wolff : please excuse.. I got the answer check below, instead of being lazy, please be more lazy for not showing up that type of comments.

Comment: Please accept my apologies, i know how can it be hard to use a search engine when other people can do it for you...

Comment: I did a lot and couldn't find anything term about delegates, I got to know about here only, and that's why I've put up a question here and got exactly what I wanted. All I was getting some functions like on() and then live() and some extras like Knockout Bindings etc. etc.... anyways, I'm glad to get an answer..

Comment: .on() is preferred to .delegate(), just read DOC. But that's ok, happen to all of us

Comment: on() didn't worked for me. delegate did. thanks to you too bro. :) no worries.

Comment: @Kandari again check DOC, you have to use delegation syntax with .on(): `$( document ).on( events, selector, data, handler );`

Comment: Exactly, it is the same, I had used on(), but never used delegate nor I was interested in it before, but when I read the DOC for delegate. I found both of them to be more or less similar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will depend on whether or not you are:

A - Setting the click event as an attribute in your HTML (This should always work)

B - Binding the event with JQuery (This will only bind to the elements which have already been rendered, should be nested in JQueries page ready function)

For both above mentioned the best approach would be to use JQueries Delegate method, see http://api.jquery.com/delegate/ for more info.

Comment: I tried both of them. but now I am able to do it with help of delegates.. thanks a lot bro. :) :)

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you have attached your function to your anchor element via javascript when page loads, maybe this way :

```
$(#yourAnchorElement).click(yourFunction);
```

When attaching events to a single or several DOM elements, we could choose to do that for the current elements **or** for current and future elements.

You should use those methods keeping the events for future elements as well.

The nice way to attach an event that would work for dinamically loaded elements is (pay attention on your jQuery version) :

```
$( selector ).live( events, data, handler );                // jQuery 1.3+
$( document ).delegate( selector, events, data, handler );  // jQuery 1.4.3+
$( document ).on( events, selector, data, handler );        // jQuery 1.7+
```

Note than from jQuery 1.7 on, methods like .click() will always work for current and future elements.

See http://api.jquery.com/live/ for futher information.

Comment: thanks bro, I've already marked that question answered. :) :) thanks

Comment: Ok, I was writing it while you marked the right answer and didn't notice :)

Comment: anyways I've marked your answer as helpful. thanks again

Answer (score 1):

jquery live event handler is not recommended in the newer versions...instead make use of jquery delegate.

refer http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

Comment: Yes brother Delegate did helped. me.. Thanks..